# Unity3D: UnityEvent with inputs does not appear in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

Does anyone know how make complex UnityEvent appear in editor?

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent myEvent;
    public UnityEvent<string> myAnotherEvent;
}
```

myEvent appears just fine, but myAnotherEvent does not.

Thanks in advance.

UPD Also tried to override the UnityEvent like:

```
public class NewEvent : UnityEvent<string>
{
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent myEvent;
    public NewEvent myAnotherEvent;
}
```

didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[System.Serializable]
public class NewEvent : UnityEvent<string>
{
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NewEvent myAnotherEvent;
}
```

You need to inform that your new class is serializable.